# How to change sharedpreferences in fxos App

Tags: firefox-os

I need to change a shared preference on fxos (firefoxOS 1.3 or newer).

The APIs C Code is reading the preference like this:

```
switch (Preferences::GetInt("dom.fmradio.band", BAND_87500_108000_kHz)) {
case BAND_76000_90000_kHz:
  mUpperBoundInKHz = 90000;
  mLowerBoundInKHz = 76000;
  break;
case BAND_76000_108000_kHz:
  mUpperBoundInKHz = 108000;
  mLowerBoundInKHz = 76000;
  break;
case BAND_87500_108000_kHz:
default:
  mUpperBoundInKHz = 108000;
  mLowerBoundInKHz = 87500;
  break;
}
```

Now I want to change "dom.fmradio.band" to "BAND_76000_108000_kHz" from within my App. Is there a WebAPI for manipulating shared preferences? If not, is there a way to edit prefs myself (I`m root on my device).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible from within an app. You can however edit it straight on your rooted device through:

- `adb shell stop b2g`
- `adb pull /data/b2g/mozilla/*.default/prefs.js prefs.js`
- Open prefs.js in a text editor, and add the pref
- Push it back: `adb push prefs.js /data/b2g/mozilla/*.default/prefs.js`
- `adb shell start b2g`

Pref syntax will be something like:

```
user_pref("dom.fmradio.band", 3);
```